# Enumerating filenames in c++

Tags: c++

I want to generate  list of enumerated filenames

```
file1.dat
file2.dat
…
```

The following code

```
#include<fstream>
for( int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    std::ofstream fout( "file" + i + ".dat", std::ios );
    //do stuff
    fout.close();
}
```

seems to be the natural implementation. Unfortunately, the integer `i` is incorrectly concatenated to the string; moreover, `ofstream` accepts a char* (not a string) as the file argument.
The following

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
string toString(int& i) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << i;
    return ss.str();
}

for( int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    std::string fileName = "file" + toString(step) + ".dat";
    std::ofstream fout( (char*)fileName.c_str(), std::ios );
    //do stuff
    fout.close();
}
```

works but is cumbersome. `(char*)fileName.c_str()` seems especially clumsy.
Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: see [boost.lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/examples.html)

Comment: `#import` ? Using Java recently (or wait is this an Objective-C thing, I have never used Objective-C)?

Comment: Oops: it should be #include, not #import. I learned java first. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possibility would be [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html):

```
std::ofstream fout(
    ("file" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i) + ".dat").c_str(),
    std::ios );
```

There is no reason to cast return value of `c_str()` to pass to `std::ofstream` constructor as it accepts a `const char*`, which is exactly what `c_str()` returns.

Or, to use your `toString()` function slightly differently:

```
std::ofstream fout(
    ("file" + toString(step) + ".dat").c_str(),
    std::ios );
```

Comment: Also: `fstream` constructors were fixed to take `const std::string&` filenames in C++11, so `c_str()` is no longer needed.

Comment: there's `ostringstream`. So adding boost dependency just for one routine is overkill.

Comment: @SigTerm, yep and he is using it: was just informing the OP of the existence of `lexical_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation doesn't do formatting, so you have to do that separately. In modern C++, you have `to_string`, and fstream objects take strings as constructor arguments:

```
std::ifstream infile(std::string("file") + std::to_string(i) + ".dat");
```

In older versions of C++ you could either use stringstreams for boost=lexical_cast to format the integer into a string, and then use the `c_str()` member function to get a char-pointer out of the string:

```
std::string filename; // populate somehow
std::ifstream infile(filename.c_str());
```